# Can not define service. Factory is missing the following properties from type is missing the following properties from type 'TypeProvider'

Tags: angular

I am injecting form validators into a service. I have the following code from the [article](https://netbasal.com/make-your-angular-forms-error-messages-magically-appear-1e32350b7fa5)

```
/**
 * Error formaters.
 */
export const defaultErrors = {
  required: (error: any): string => `This field is required.`,
  minlength: ({requiredLength, actualLength}): string => {
    return `Expect ${requiredLength} but got ${actualLength}`;
  }
};

/**
 * Error formaters injected.
 */
export const FORM_ERRORS = new InjectionToken('FORM_ERRORS', {
  // providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => defaultErrors
});
```

It produces the error.

```
 is missing the following properties from type 'TypeProvider': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 5 more.
```

I understand that I need to read the documentation carefully... It is still unresolved.

Comment: works perfectly here [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-terms-and-conditions-reactive-forms?embed=1&file=src/app/form-errors.ts)

Comment: Should I make tsconfig less strict?

Comment: "Should I make tsconfig less strict" what have you changed in tsconfig? works fine locally my cli generated `tsconfig.json` for reference `{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the problem was childish. I injected this way.

```
@inject(FORM_ERRORS) private errors,
```

The right is with capital **I**

```
@Inject(FORM_ERRORS) private errors,
```